# Flutter Firestore calculations not working

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, numeric

## Objective

I've got a Firestore app that logs items and their value in a document. I want to return the "Value" field of all those documents and calculate the total value of all of them (add them up).

## Issue

When I use the below line of code, it just prints the values one by one (see screenshot attached). I've also attached a screenshot of my Firestore structure. I've tried using sum and sum2 but both return the same result.

```
 var getValueSTRING = documentSnapshot['Value'];
 var one = int.parse(getValueSTRING);
 var sum = [values].reduce((curr, next) => curr + next);
 var sum2 = list2.fold(0, (curr, next) => curr + next);
 print(sum);
```

## Results Produced

```
Reloaded 3 of 579 libraries in 446ms.
I/flutter ( 3161): [100]
I/flutter ( 3161): [200]
```

[Firestore Structure Here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47246858/65860819-f0eee900-e362-11e9-88a8-f45e1dbe9a69.png)

## Code

```
class Expenses extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ESTATE createState() => ESTATE();
}

class ESTATE extends State<Expenses> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(userDocPATH.toString())
            .collection(userCardPATH.toString())
            .document(selectedCardPATH)
            .collection('Expenses')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                    snapshot.data.documents[index];


                var getValueSTRING = documentSnapshot['Value'];
                var one = int.parse(getValueSTRING);
                var list2 = [one];
                var sum2 = list2.fold(0, (curr, next) => curr + next);
                print(sum2);

                return Text(documentSnapshot['Value']);
              });
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a `QuerySnapshot snapshot` at the ready. You can calculate the sum of all values like so:

```
final sum = snapshot.data.documents.fold(0, (prev, next) => prev + int.parse(next['Value']))
```

In other words, folding should be performed on `List<DocumentSnapshot>`.

**Edit in response to updated code:**

The culprit are these lines:

```
var one = int.parse(getValueSTRING);
var list2 = [one];
var sum2 = list2.fold(0, (curr, next) => curr + next);
```

The problem is that the code tries to fold a list that has only one value. Summing list with one item will always net a sum equal to that item's value.

To get the correct value all `DocumentSnapshots` need to be taken into account. Currently, only one `DocumentSnapshot` is considered, as indicated by this line:

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
```

Instead, try something like this (I've omitted unnecessary code to reduce visual noise):

```
<...>
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  // Add this line to calculate total sum, and use it later on
  final sum = snapshot.data.documents.fold(0.0, (prev, next) => prev + int.parse(next['Value']))
  return ListView.builder(<...>);
```

**Edit 2 (working code):**

Assume the following Firebase Database structure:

```
Expenses > doc1 > Value: "100"
           doc2 > Value: "200"
           doc3 > Value: "300"
```

The code below calculates the sum and displays it as a header. It also shows each individual value. As long as Firebase structure is the same, the code should run and produce correct results. Adding a new document or editing existing one will affect both list of entries and total sum.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Expenses());
}

class Expenses extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ESTATE createState() => ESTATE();
}

class ESTATE extends State<Expenses> {
  final collection = Firestore.instance.collection('Expenses');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: collection.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          final documents = snapshot.data.documents;
          final sum = documents.fold(0, (s, n) => s + int.parse(n['Value']));
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Total sum: $sum")),
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                final value = int.parse(documentSnapshot['Value']);
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('Document $index: $value'),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @cegas, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this hasn't worked, I've updated my original message with the full code for this page. When I run your suggestion, the below error appears. 
  `Class 'String' has no instance method 'fold'.` `Tried calling: fold(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic)` `Receiver: "100" `

Comment: I've updated the answer. In short, it seems that only one document snapshot is being considered, and a list of one value is being folded (sum of which will always be equal to that item's value).

Comment: Hi @cegas thanks for your suggestion unfortunately the same thing was happening. I've done some further testing (and head banging against the desk) and found that it's because my `['Value']` results are being displayed one line at a time - therefore being treated as separate calculations. For example running `var t = [1,2,3]` returns me `[1,2,3]` all on the same line but if I run ` var tt = [documentSnapshot['Value]]` I get the `[Value]` on seperate lines. Do you know how I can keep these all on the same line so that the fold op treats them all together instead of separately. Thanks, T.

Comment: This is what I was alluding to: you're retrieving a value as `DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index]`. You are using an index to retrieve a specific (single) document out of all the snapshots while building a `ListView`. I.e., `snapshot.data.documents[index]` returns a single document, hence `snapshot['Value']` returns a value for that specific document. If you wish to sum all values of the documents, you have to operate on all of the documents. Does that make sense or am I misinterpreting the question? I can include a working example later today to illustrate this.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, at the moment I am returning a single document and anything that interacts with that document data gets treated separately (per doc). My question now I suppose, is how do I treat the data as a whole as opposed to individually? An example of this would be fab thank you!

Comment: I've added a working example of how to have both a list of entries and something that needs to consider all of the documents (in this case, `sum`, but could be anything). Note that my Firebase structure differs slightly from yours, so be sure to adjust for that. Other than that, is that what you were aiming for? Unless I misunderstood the original question, I believe the code above should address it. If problems still persist I think a new question is warranted - we're straying a bit from the original one. I'd be happy to assist on the new question, too, of course.

Comment: I don't think you could have made me any happier. So chuffed to see this finally working! Sorry the question started getting a little off topic but I really appreciate you taking the time to help me on this one. I've marked your response as the solution.

Comment: Hey, no worries - happy that it worked out for you!

Answer (score -1):

final collection = Firestore.instance.collection('Expenses');
// how to get uid then docs???